# WebGL textmesh character not showing on browser

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

WebGL textmesh font only show in the game view but not in the browser.

**Game View**

[image: game view]

**WebGL View**

[image: webgl view]

the `#` character with red color is fine, but `█` with blue color is not working, is it because of the character i'm using is not currently supported ?.
since the settings is same like the red color, so i believe it is related to the character.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since WebGL is quite new, some of special character would not be render by browser.

https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/certain-special-text-characters-dont-show-up-in-game-in-webgl